# Android - Unable to access some classes under **package android.telephony**

Tags: java, android, reflection, android-source, telephony

I am trying to access classes stored under `android.telephony` package using reflection but for some classes I am getting `ClassNotFoundException`.

Can anyone tell me why some classes can be accessed and some are not even though this classes reside within the same package ?

Ex: `public class TelephonyManager` can be accessed using reflection as shown below

```
try {
Class<?> manager1 = Class.forName("android.telephony.TelephonyManager");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

`public class SubscriptionManager` cannot be accessed using reflection

```
try {
Class<?> subscriptionManager = Class.forName("android.telephony.SubscriptionManager");
//Throwing error
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
e1.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

both classes belong to the same package `android.telephony`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because [`SubscriptionManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager.html) was just added in API 22, and the phone or emulator you are using does not have Android 5.1.

That's how reflection is supposed to work! If a class is not present, the `ClassNotFoundException` is thrown.

Comment: I have downloaded source code of android 22 and 21 in same repository and I think GIT have merged both of them together. That caused confusion.

Comment: Oh, I see :) Do you need them both for making two separate builds ?

Comment: No. Just removed 22 ;)